# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Book'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some data in a .txt file that looks like this:

```
-[TradingDesk;ValDate;Book;ProductClass]
-[Example;10/02/2019; Expenses; Provisions and Costs]
```

I have to select only the book that matches with 'Expenses'.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv(r'path')
Expenses = data[data.Book == 'Expenses']
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Book'

Comment: Example of list:
[Example;10/02/2019; Expenses; Provisions and Costs]
[Example;10/02/2019; Overnight; Trades]
[Example;10/02/2019; Cash; Cash]
[Example;10/02/2019; Expenses; Provisions]

Comment: try data['Book']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `delimiter` or `sep` because the default is set with commas `,` and probably the separation is not done correctly. Furthermore passing the name of the column between brackets (with the separation done correctly) should help you solve the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv(r'path',delimiter=';')
Expenses = data[data['Book'] == 'Expenses']
```

Comment: and try printing df.head(x) (replace x with a reasonably small number)